If $a<b$ and $c<d$, prove $c-b<d-a$.
There's a problem in my precalculus textbook that does not have an answer.
If $a<b$ and $c<d$, prove $c-b<d-a$.
My proof was as follows:
$$
c-b<d-a \Rightarrow a-b < d-c
$$
$$
\text{Given } a < b,\ a-b < 0
$$
$$
\text{Given } c < d,\ d-c > 0
$$
$$
a-b < d-c\ \blacksquare
$$
Is this correct? I found this question, which is essentially the reverse of my question, which makes me think it's correct, but I would like verification before I move on.

Since the first line is $c-b<d-a\Rightarrow a-b<d-c$ and your conclusion is $a-b<d-c$, no, this isn't correct.

Instead of $
c-b<d-a \Rightarrow a-b < d-c
$ you should write $
c-b<d-a \Leftarrow a-b < d-c
$

This shows the importance/usefulnes of using double-sided implication signs whenever possible in proving inequalities

To put in a general way what is said by @SassatelliGiulio above, you have started your proof by assuming the thing that has to be proved (namely, the inequality $c-b<d-a$) which is immediately a fatal logical error.

From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and have specific concerns or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough.

@LeeMosher I suppose what confuses me is knowing the inequality $c-b<d-a$ is equivalent to writing $a-b<d-c$. It does not feel like assuming $c-b<d-a$ is true, simply rewriting it. Later showing that $a-b$ must be negative if $a<b$ and $d-c$ must be positive if $c<d$ shows the original equation will always state that a positive is greater than a negative.

In that case you should pay attention to the other suggestions found here, and learn to write logical connectives correctly. You are correct that the inequality $c-b<d-a$ is "just rewriting" the inequality $a-b<d-c$, but you are not expressing that properly. For the correct expression (as others have said here), instead of using "implies" connective $\implies$, you should use the "if and only if" connective $\iff$.

You have written '$P\Rightarrow Q$ is true' and then proved $Q$ to be true.
Unfortunately, this doesn't tell us anything about the truth of $P$, due to the nature of the material implication binary operator.
Instead you should have written '$Q$ is true, $Q\Rightarrow P$ is true, therefore $P$ is true.'

Thanks for your response; I'm trying to re-evaluate given your answer. Isn't the inequality $c-b<d-a$ equivalent to $a-b<d-c$? Can't I rewrite it that way to prove that the left side will always be negative and the right side always positive?

You haven't written equivalent ($\equiv$ or $\iff$). You've written implies ($\Rightarrow$ or $\implies$ or $\to$), which is a different operator. Either using equivalent or reversing the clauses in your original post makes it a proof.

if $a<b$ then $-b<-a$ and you can apply the same proof as the another question with $-b<-a$ and $c<d$.
The question if $a-b<d-c$ is correct. $a-b$ is a negative number and $d-c$ is positive
